# Weird C# Pinvoke SetWinEventHook bug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winapi, com, pinvoke

I am currently running into a really weird bug when using Pinvoke to call the [SetWinEventHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

I am using SetWinEventHook (through Pinvoke) to hook the window creation event so that my C# function will get called every time a new window is created. Here is the code for my hooked function :

```
lock(_lock)
{
    // check if the window handler is valid
    isValidWindow = check();
    if (isValidWindow) //L1
    {
        //do something if the window handler is valid
        doSomething() //L2
    }
}
```

For some reason when I am debugging this code in visual studio, if I set a breakpoint in L2, and proceed to open a new window, the breakpoint at L2 never gets triggered.

However, if I set a breakpoint at L1 as well as L2, then proceed to open up a new window, then the breakpoint at L2 (and L1) would trigger.

I tested it multiple times and this behavior is the same every time.

Comment: Eric's answer is probably right. But you didn't really help yourself by removing most of the code. Would have been easy to supply SSCCE.

Answer (score 3):

Triggering a breakpoint switches to Visual Studio, which takes focus, sending its *own* set of windows events.  Unless you're debugging remotely (either a separate machine or a VM), you will have all sorts of weird behaviors when debugging WinEvents.